# How can I disable background on material ui modal?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I use the material ui modal component and still have access to the background behind what the modal is displaying? Is this possible? I know that you can change the background color with backdropProps, but is there a way to disable the background entirely and still be able to edit things in the background while it is open?

Comment: I think it is not possible as material-ui creates a complete page overlay using React Portal and then put modal into that. So you can't interact with the background without closing the modal.

Comment: Can you specify which version of material-UI you are using? In the latest version, https://material-ui.com/api/modal/ - it provides `container` prop. You can create your own portal and mount material-UI modal into it and then you can interact with background elements.

Comment: is there another type of pop up on material ui that does not adjust to its parent containers and still has the background editable? @aditya81070

Comment: No, I think. Material-UI uses this overlay thing in all its components as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `hideBackdrop` property, and pass it `true` so it will not even render the backdrop, therefore allowing you to interact with the whatever is behind the modal.

Docs here https://v3.material-ui.com/api/modal/